# Need examples for Unicode SQL queries

Tags: sql

I need few examples for Unicode SQL queries.
Also, i need to understand fully about Unicode. Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both parts of your question are way too broad. For the second part see [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

tsql:

```
insert into Table1(col1) values(N'unicode text ☻');
```